# URI encode query parameter in request

Tags: node.js, request

I want to replicate the below curl request in node using request module.

`curl -X POST \
  'https://control.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?authkey=fdfdfdfdfdfd&mobile=%203456786444&message=Your%20OTPis%20456897&otp=456897' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'`

How ever when I tried the below code where I have used `qs` object to send the query parameters seems the `+` in mobile number is not uri encoded as above. How can I achieve this. Is `qs` is not the right parameter ? I have also tried using `form` .

My node code

```
var request = require('request');

request.post(
{
    url:'https://control.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php',
    headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
    qs  : {
            authkey:'fdfdfdfdfdfd',
            message:'Your OTP is 456789',
            mobile :'+3456786444',
            otp: '456789'
}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
      console.log(err);
 });
```

Comment: In the query string, `+` should be encoded as `%2B`, not `%20`.

Comment: Curl works fine. My. Node code is not working.

Comment: Running your code locally, with `request` version 2.83.0, produces a request with this query string: `authkey=fdfdfdfdfdfd&message=Your%20OTP%20is%20456789&mobile=%2B3456786444&otp=456789` which has the `+` symbol encoded correctly.

Comment: Have you printed the req object ? Will check about version.

Comment: I used [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to intercept and view the raw HTTP request. A couple other things you might want to consider... do you even need the + in the mobile number? The [documentation](https://api.msg91.com/apidoc/sendotp/send-otp.php) for that service appears to show you can just send the raw number. And they offer a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendotp) which might be easier to use than raw API calls.